# Join two records from same model in django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

Been searching the web for a couple hours now looking for a solution but nothing quite fits what I am looking for.

I have one model (simplified):

```
class SimpleModel(Model):
    name = CharField('Name', unique=True)
    date = DateField()
    amount = FloatField()
```

I have two dates; `date_one` and `date_two`.

I would like a single queryset with a row for each name in the Model, with each row showing:

`{'name': name, 'date_one': date_one, 'date_two': date_two, 'amount_one': amount_one, 'amount_two': amount_two, 'change': amount_two - amount_one}`

Reason being I would like to be able to find the rank of `amount_one`, `amount_two`, and `change`, using sort or filters on that single queryset.

I know I could create a list of dictionaries from two separate querysets then sort on that and get the ranks from the index values ...

but perhaps nievely I feel like there should be a DB solution using one queryset that would be faster.

`union` seemed promising but you cannot perform some simple operations like `filter` after that

I think I could perhaps split name into its own Model and generate queryset with related fields, but I'd prefer not to change the schema at this stage. Also, I only have access to sqlite.

appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current model forces you to have ONE name associated with ONE date and ONE amount. Because `name` is `unique=True`, **you literally cannot have two dates associated with the same name**

So if you want to be able to have several dates/amounts associated with a name, there are several ways to proceed

**Idea 1:** If there will only be 2 dates and 2 amounts, simply add a second date field and a second amount field

**Idea 2:** If there can be an infinite number of days and amounts, you'll have to change your model to reflect it, by having :

- A model for your names
- A model for your days and amounts, with a foreign key to your names

**Idea 3:** You could keep the same model and simply remove the `unique` constraint, but that's a recipe for mistakes

Based on your choice, you'll then have several ways of querying what you need. It depends on your final model structure. The best way to go would be to create custom model methods that query the 2 dates/amount, format an array and return it